# Marker animation drop callback

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, callback

I'm working with google maps, I have this `_marker()` function. I am currently using a `setTimeout` with 6 seconds to delay the callback so that it runs after the marker has been dropped. I've been looking in the documentation and tried something like `gmaps.event.addListenerOnce(marker, 'idle', function(...` with no luck. Does anyone know of a marker animation-drop event so I can legitimize this callback?

```
var _marker = function(place, map, callback){
    var marker = new gmaps.Marker({
        clickable: false,
        draggable: false,
        position: new gmaps.LatLng(place.latitude, place.longitude),
        map: map,
        animation: gmaps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: new gmaps.MarkerImage(
            'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png',
            new gmaps.Size(32, 32),
            new gmaps.Point(0,0),
            new gmaps.Point(16, 32)
        )
    });
    if(typeof callback !== "undefined"){
        setTimeout(function(){
            return callback(marker);
        }, 600);
    }else{
        return marker;
    }
}
```

Comment: How does one drop a marker? By clicking on the map? If so the callback should be after click event not after Animation event.

Comment: The marker drops when map loads & `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a delayMarker function kind of works the same way as the original one, unless there's a method that allows you to create a marker without showing it, then show and animate it, I'm not sure if there's a better way.

[Demo on JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/vileqotubi/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var googleMapsIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
    'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red-dot.png',
    new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(16, 32)
  )

  function delayMarker ({place = {}, position, map, timeout}, callback) {

    var marker = {
      clickable: false,
      draggable: false,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(position.lat, position.lng),
      map: map,
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
      icon: googleMapsIcon
    }

    if (timeout && callback) {
      return setTimeout(function(){
        return callback(new google.maps.Marker(marker))
      }, timeout)  
    } else {
      return marker  
    }
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: myLatLng,
    scrollwheel: false,
    zoom: 4
  })

  var marker = delayMarker({
    map: map,
    position: myLatLng,
    timeout: 2000,
  }, () => {
    console.log('done')
  })

}
```